# Not downloading a file if download URL is of different localhost port

Tags: javascript, html, apache, jetty, cross-domain

I am having a text file and wants to download. I am working in localhost. The HTML page from which I am downloading file, is called from localhost:8080. And the file which I want to download, I am calling using another port i.e. 'localhost:100'.

If I do like this I am not getting that particular txt file, in fact the whole location of the of the folder is getting downloaded in HTML format.
How to resolve this issue ?

But when the port is same for both HTML and the download URL , that particular text file is getting downloaded.

**EDIT**

**HTML Page (http://localhost:8080/project/test.html)**

```
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var url="http://localhost:100/test";
        var file = "test112.zip";
        saveFile(url,file);  // Text Document
        alert("File is downloaded");

        function saveFile(fileURL,fileName){

             if (!window.ActiveXObject) {
            var save = document.createElement('a');
            save.href = fileURL;
            save.target = '_blank';
            save.download = fileName || fileURL;
            var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            save.dispatchEvent(evt);
            (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
            }        
        }

    </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

When this runs following file gets downloaded -

> download.html

In download.html there is

> Index of /test

The *localhost:8080 is Jetty Server* and *localhost:100 is Apache Server*

Comment: This is impossible to answer. You haven't shown us how the server is set up, you haven't shown us your server side code, you haven't shown us your client side code, and you haven't shown us how you trigger the "download".

Comment: @Quentin Sorry  I will put the codes .

Comment: I am not getting any help !